# Imported components transformed into "/static" urls in react-create-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app, react-router-dom

I'm having an issue I can't really find any previous answers to or documentation about.

I'm loading a component, in a module, on my local machine, "login.jsx," into an "index.js":

```
import Login from './login';

export { Login };
```

The exported component inside "login.jsx" is very basic.

The module main points directly to the index.js file and I'm importing it into the "App.js" file generated by create-react-app.

The directory structure of the module is as follows:

```
module
   | src
   | --- components
   | --- --- login.jsx
   | --- --- index.js
   | package.json
```

It is worth noting that this is also a create-react-app, but none of the generated files are part of the main exports of the linked module.

When I import it, and console.log, it is imported as a string: "/static/media/login.1d0b2e37.jsx."

Specifically, the error I'm getting is:

```
Invalid tag: /static/media/login.1d0b2e37.jsx
```

Because I am attempting to load the import:

```
import { Login } from 'component-module';
```

directly into a react-router-dom route. All components that live directly in my create-react-app folder, "src," render just fine.

When logging:

```
console.log(Login);
```

after the import, it is immediately clear that it is a string: "/static/media/login.1d0b2e37.jsx."

The directory structure of my create-react-app project is (a generic create-react-app):

```
create-react-app
   | src
   | --- App.js
```

In which exists the aforementioned import, which is resulting in importing `Login` as a string.

Is there some weirdness going on here with the create-react-app development server rendering of external components? Maybe in one of the Webpack plugins thats just treating externals as static?

As far as I can tell, there is no information about this in the [create-react-app docs](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md)

Comment: Can you post your directory structure? And your import/export statements as you have it in your codebase.

Comment: @kngroo I updated to add directory structures. All of the imports/exports I think are already demonstrated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By module, do you mean a library? As in something you can install as a dependency for other apps via npm install?

If so, CRA is not designed for that purpose. It is intended for creating apps.

If you really see the need to create a library for a login component, and want to do so using CRA, you can follow this guide: https://medium.com/@lokhmakov/best-way-to-create-npm-packages-with-create-react-app-b24dd449c354 or use [this tool](https://github.com/UdiliaInc/create-react-library), although I have never tried it myself and cannot vouch for it.

Is there a good reason for implementing your component as a library though?
Libraries are mainly intended for sharing generic functionality with developers for use in their individual applications.

If you only intend to use this component in your particular app, I would suggest implementing it as a component within your app. You can still implement it as a standalone library, but without needing to set up the build logic.

```
create-react-app
|src
|    App.js
|    components
|        Login
|            index.js
|            Login.jsx
```

And in App.js `import Login from './components/Login`

Comment: "Is there a good reason for implementing your component as a library though? Libraries are mainly intended for sharing generic functionality with developers for use in their individual applications." <- That IS why. :) For those components I plan to share them for use in multiple projects.

Comment: So you're suggestion, based on that article, is to try manually manipulating the webpack.dev.js? CRA may not be intended for this use case, but because normal modules (like react-router-dom) expose components in a similar fashion to this, I feel like it should work. webpack.dev.js could be a good place to start. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I ended up just ejecting here and basically rewriting the webpack.dev.js file

Answer (score -3):

I try to rename my file contain the export to .js file. And it works like a charm